# What's the role of EX stage for branching in Pipelined MIPS w Forwarding?

Tags: mips, cpu-architecture, pipelining

Consider the following Pipelined Processor structure:

[image: MIPS Schema](![a busy cat]

Notice that the condition test for branching (the = circuit), as well as the target address calculation for the next instruction in case of branch taken are executed in the ID phase - as a way to save on stalls/flushes (as opposed to doing all that in the EX phase and forwarding the results in the MEM phase of the given branch instruction).

Since all the work gets done in Instruction Decode stage, why bother waiting for the given branching instruction to reach the EX stage? Does the EX stage ALU unit have a role in this, somehow?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When the `beq` presents a control hazard, the pipelined processor does not know in advance what instruction to fetch next,because the branch decision has not been made by the time the next instruction is fetched.

Because the decision is made in the MEM-stage we need to stall the pipeline for three cycles at every branch which of course effect the system performance.

another way is to predict whether the branch will be taken and begin to executing instructions based on the prediction.Once the branch decision is made and is available, the processor can throw out(flushes) the instructions if the prediction was wrong (this called branch misprediction penalty)  which also effect the performance.

To reduce the branch misprediction penalty one could make the branch decision made earlier.
Making the decision simply requires comparing two registers. using a dedicated equality comparator is faster than performing a subtraction and zero detection. If the comparator is fast enough, it could be moved back into the Decode stage, so that the operands are read from the register file and compared to determine the next PC by the end of the Decode stage.

Unfortunately the early branch decision hardware introduce a new RAW *data hazard*.

Comment: `Because the decision is made in the MEM-stage`  Sorry but I fail to understand this? As per the attached diagram, the decision is made in DEC-stage itself. Also, the final target address computation is moved to DEC-stage. So, the branch should be resolved in the DEC-stage and not in MEM-stage?

Comment: Yes. I see it now. But still it doesn't seem to answe the query the OP had - "if all the work is done in the decode stage why are we still waiting for the EX stage?" You have mentioned the conditions under which the comparison hardware can be moved to the DEC stage.

Comment: The comparison hardware make the decision earlier in the Decode stage. that's why you have them to move back the decision making from the MEM stage, hope it helped.

Comment: Moving the compare as early as DEC would be a problem for branching on the result of an ALU instruction, like the very common `slt` / `bnez` sequence.  [How does MIPS I handle branching on the previous ALU instruction without stalling?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58601958) explains that this isn't what commercial MIPS R2000 actually did.

Answer (score 0):

> Since all the work gets done in Instruction Decode stage, why bother waiting for the given branching instruction to reach the EX stage? Does the EX stage ALU unit have a role in this, somehow?

The branch instruction is decoded and resolved in the Decode stage only and we do not wait for it to go to the EX stage.

Like you pointed out in the question, both the branch result and the target address calculation is done in the DEC stage. The hardware takes care of the `RAW` hazards by forwarding the required data from the correct stages (notice the little mux'es right after the RegFile is read). As a result the branch equality check sees the correct operands and the result drives the `PCSrcD` signal. This signal further decides the output of the first Mux in the diagram (which essentially decides between `PC+4` or `Branch Target`. Hence it becomes safe and quick to do this in the DEC stage itself.

Also, none of the  branch instruction related signals (`PCSrcD`, `BranchD`, `PCBranchD`) make it to the EX stage. If you see the inputs to the ISS/EX register, it doesn't take in any of the above mentioned signals. Hence, the information isn't passed the to EX stage and the branch is completely resolved and retired at the end of the `DEC` stage itself.